# Exchanging code for access token fails when using Sign in with Google in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

We have an application that uses Dropbox API. When the user goes through the Dropbox OAuth 2 flow and signs-in using their email address and password, all works fine and we get the `access_token`. However, when the user uses the "Sign in with Google" flow in the Dropbox authorization dialog, we get back `code` which we then try to exchange for access token but the request fails with `{"error_description": "code doesn't exist or has expired", "error": "invalid_grant"}`.

Here's the steps we use:

1.

```
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ clientId: clientId });
var authUrl = dbx.getAuthenticationUrl('https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver');
```

This gives us url `https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=...&redirect_uri=https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver`.

2.
 Open `authUrl` in a popup.

3.
 User uses "Sign in with Google"

4.
 We get a redirect to the URL below that contains the code:
`https://www.dropbox.com/google/authcallback?state=...&code=...&scope=...`

Now trying to exchange the code for access token with POST to `https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token` gives us:
`{"error_description": "code doesn't exist or has expired", "error": "invalid_grant"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, given the use of the Google Sign In flow, there are actually two OAuth authorization flow instances occurring; the Google Sign In flow is nested inside the Dropbox app authorization flow. Your app doesn't actually need to know about this though.

That `https://www.dropbox.com/google/authcallback` URL is Dropbox's redirect URL for the Google Sign In flow, and accordingly the `code` given there is for the Google OAuth flow, not the Dropbox OAuth flow. Attempting to use it for the Dropbox OAuth 2 flow will accordingly fail as you've seen (since it actually came from Google, not Dropbox).

You should have your app wait until your own redirect URL (in your shared code, `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver`) is accessed, and only then take the `code` from there and exchange it for a Dropbox access token.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! It works like a charm now. Our app is an Electron app and so we just react on the will-navigate and did-get-redirect-request and check if the URL passed as parameters to these event handlers is our redirect URL with: url.startsWith(redirectUri).